# Generate reports of specs run through "cypress open" app

Tags: cypress

I have reporter (mochawesome) set in cypress.json.

The thing is that this reporter is generating report .json and html files only when i run tests with "cypress run" command.

Is there a way to get reports for tests run via Cypress gui app ("cypress open") after clicking each individual test?

I'm on Ubuntu 18 and Cypress 5.5.0

Comment: I do not have a way to do such feat but may be a run with this command will help: npx cypress run --headed --spec [pathToFileToRun]

Comment: @RosenMihaylov this might be workaround, still it would be nice to have this ability via "cypress open"

Answer (score 0):

Cypress wont publish results on a file, for tests run by test-runner